# How to update row based on multiple condition

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a df

```
+------+-------+-----+
|values|percent|ecpc |
+------+-------+-----+
|  010 |  0.11 |    5|
|  100 |  0.22 |    4|
|  001 |  0.33 |    3|
|  011 |  0.01 |    5|
|  101 |  0.005|    4|
|  110 |  0.11 |    3|
|  000 |  0.21 |    5|
|  111 |0.0001 |    4|
+------+-------+-----+
```

If percent `< 0.01` ,I wanna change values one of `1` to `0`. 
AND Changed percent `> 0.01`, change ecpc to new ecpc.

EX: for values 111, percent`<0.01`, change one of `1` to `0`, like `101`,
still percent`< 0.01`, change other 1, like 110, percent`>0.01`  is `0.11`,
change another 1, like 011, percent`>0.01` is 0.01. `0.01 <0.11` . 
Update ecpc to 5 when `values = 111`.

Final DF like :

```
+------+-------+-----+------+
|values|percent|ecpc |change|
+------+-------+-----+------+
|  010 |  0.11 |    5|     0|
|  100 |  0.22 |    4|     0|
|  001 |  0.33 |    3|     0|
|  011 |  0.01 |    5|     0|
|  101 |  0.005|    5|     1|
|  110 |  0.11 |    3|     0|
|  000 |  0.21 |    5|     0|
|  111 |0.0001 |    3|     1|
+------+-------+-----+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you want to update a row on a single condition (e.g. change = 1 when percent < 0.11 and 0 otherwise). You would do something like this:

```
val newDF = df.withColumn("change", when($"percent" < 0.11, lit(1)).otherwise(lit(0))
```

When you are doing addition changes just chain them:

```
val newDFCombined = newDF.withColumn("ecpc", when($"percent" < 0.11, myFunc1($"values").otherwise(myFunc2($"values"))))
```

where myFunc1 and MyFunc2 are the functions to calculate the value you want.